# Enforcing parameter combinations with typescript

Tags: typescript, generics

I have the following code:

```
enum ParamOneType {
  Round,
  Square,
}

interface PossibleValues {
  [ParamOneType.Round]: 'a' | 'b';
  [ParamOneType.Square]: 'c' | 'd';
}

const indexRound = {
  a: 'whatever',
  b: 'whatever',
};

const doSomething = <T extends ParamOneType>(
  paramOne: T,
  paramTwo: PossibleValues[T],
): void => {
  switch (paramOne) {
    case ParamOneType.Round: {
      // Type 'PossibleValues[T]' cannot be used to index type '{ a: string; b: string; }'
      const b = indexRound[paramTwo];
    }
  }
};
```

Why do I get the error `Type 'PossibleValues[T]' cannot be used to index type '{ a: string; b: string; }'` here? Intellisense does seem to pick up the function signature correctly, for example my autocomplete in VSCode shows:

```
const doSomething: <ParamOneType.Round>(paramOne: ParamOneType.Round, paramTwo: "a" | "b") => void
```

when calling the function as `doSomething(ParamOneType.Round, 'a')`

Comment: You get this error because `paramTwo` cannot be used to index `indexRound`. There is no information about `PossibleValues[T]` being a `keyof typeof indexRound`.

Comment: If you tell typescript that it is one like this: `const b = indexRound[paramTwo as keyof typeof indexRound];` It will work as expected.

Comment: Yeah, but that’s just casting it. My confusion stems from the fact that if paramOne is Round, paramTwo can only be ‘a’ or ‘b’ according to the function signature. Shouldn’t these be seen as valid indexes? If I change it to the string itself there is no error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this example, where you do a `switch` on `paramOne`, I'd stay away from [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html), which cannot be [narrowed by control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis).  It's always possible that `T` could be the full `ParamOneType` type, at which point someone could call `doSomething()` with parameters you don't expect, like `doSomething( Math.random()<0.99 ? ParamOneType.Round : ParamOneType.Square,  "c")`, which has a 99% chance of being bad.  This makes narrowing inside generic functions tricky.  It's a known issue, and there are multiple feature requests for some way to improve it. See [microsoft/TypeScript#27808](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27808) or [microsoft/TypeScript#33014](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33014) for more information.

Instead, you can give `doSomething` a [rest parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) whose type is a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) of [rest tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#rest-elements-in-tuple-types), and immediately [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) into the two variables `paramOne` and `paramTwo`.

```
type DoSomethingParams =
 [paramOne: ParamOneType.Round, paramTwo: "a" | "b"] | 
 [paramOne: ParamOneType.Square, paramTwo: "c" | "d"]

const doSomething = ([paramOne, paramTwo]: DoSomethingParams): void => { }
```

You can see that this behaves as desired from the caller's side:

```
doSomething(ParamOneType.Round, "a") // okay
doSomething(ParamOneType.Round, "c") // error
doSomething(ParamOneType.Square, "c") // okay
doSomething(ParamOneType.Square, "b") // error
```

And since TypeScript 4.6 and above supports [control flow analysis for destructured discriminated unions](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-6/#cfa-destructured-discriminated-unions), you can switch on `paramOne` in the implementation and the compiler will automatically narrow `paramTwo` accordingly:

```
const doSomething = (...[paramOne, paramTwo]: DoSomethingParams): void => {
  switch (paramOne) {
    case ParamOneType.Round: {
      const b = indexRound[paramTwo]; // okay
    }
  }
};
```

Also note that you can generate the above `DoSomethingParams` type programmatically from `PossibleValues`, as follows:

```
type DoSomethingParams = { [T in ParamOneType]:
  [paramOne: T, paramTwo: PossibleValues[T]]
}[ParamOneType]
```

This is called a *distributive object type* (as coined in [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109)) where you immediately [index into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) to get a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of `[paramOne: T, paramTwo: PossibleValues[T]]` for every `T` in `PossibleValues`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBACghgJzhA8iYAVAngB2FAbwCgooAlAezBABMAaEqAZQEcxFgGBfIogSxAAXYAgBmcAMb4YFAM6y+AIwA2wAGpxlYYLMKMA2vCSp02PADpK1GgF0AXFADkcR1AA+TxY4DcBo8jRMXGBzVnYEYHsnCVcPRxofIh4iCQoQWUEoARpgAA8rWigAXj1SOAdHAHcACzhhADcRRwZSRQqauuBGhGak3yJBYKgAEQomCghgQWqBAHN-CF0Sgih9DCyQWEQA02D7Axxtk2AHDDooQ+MMSooHGXklVQ0tHTWbGyTDI8CzSN4AegAVFBBngRmMJlMZiB5kcliR9JcdictsYfsFLFRaOckRBrrcoAAiOCE9xExSEmxkhG4wJ3b67CxhDg4o74hyEiSkjyEmiUoiA-4pNIZKA0CGTaZzYpQAAU5gViIZnAubJuUVG40l0NhxlkAEoHPUKHwaMUAHylKCySp8QQSapy2nofVW0gSOCyaTK36Y6wOYikINQVLpTKKGXZPIFGhKq7q7xQf7-KAUADWcCwjFIPBzfV44q1ULmsoW6IsMfOxMJruTqYzWcLkKlMNLPoxlaJXNrKZECAoCCITe1JbLjJCzIiVe7SZT6czQ4lxdbY6CTLYLPJNdnUD7A6AA)